# The sequence $\sigma_n$=$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^nz_n}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $$\sigma_n=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^nz_n}{n+1}$$ I need to prove that

1. if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}z_n$=1 then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sigma_n$=1 and
2. I need to find out if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sigma_n$=0 implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z_n=0$.

For 1) I'm not sure how to begin.
And for 2) I know that if the series converges then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}z_n$=0 so I only need to examine the cases when $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sigma_n$=0 and the series diverges, but I can't think of a counterexample to the statement or a proof of it.

Comment: Minor nit: There is no “series” here, only sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z_n\to 1$, then $\sigma_n\to 1$ as well.

Indeed, suppose that $b_n:=z_n-1$. Then $b_n\to 0$ and it suffices to show that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{b_1+\dots+b_n}{n}=0$. Since $b_n\to 0$ then there is $c>0$ ushc that for all $n$ we have $|b_n|<c$. Moreover, for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_0=n_0(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $|b_n|<\epsilon$.

Hence $$\left|\dfrac{b_1+\dots+b_{n_0}+b_{n_0+1}+\dots+b_n}{n}\right|\leq \dfrac{cn_0}{n}+\dfrac{(n-n_0)\epsilon}{n}<2\epsilon,$$ if $n>\max \{n_0,cn_0/\epsilon\}$. It proves 1).

For 2) If $z_n=(-1)^n,$ then $\sigma_n\to 0$ but $z_n$ diverges.